# How can I detect action which Settings/Apps Manager is opened or not in android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, android-settings

I am developing security app in android.
I want that user can't uninstall and force stop my app so that can't access Application Detail Screen.
But so I have used several solutions from StackOverFlow. But I haven't found right solution yet.
The solutions are different from Android 4,5 and 6.
Please let me know if you have correct solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wording of your question is difficult to understand, but it sounds like you want to create a Kiosk app?

Some behaviors of a Kiosk app is what you described. If your app acts like a home screen and you have no other home screen installed it will start on boot and you won't be able to exit it.

The basis for creating a Kiosk app is using

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

If you want some source you can look at Anderweb's ADW Launcher https://github.com/AnderWeb/android_packages_apps_Launcher

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it is useful. But this launcher can be uninstalled. I want to make disable Settings/Apps Manager. Is it possible?

Comment: My answer is how you do that. Start by having the setup I described. And then override and handle menu/back device button functionality. Note by doing so your app will not be accepted by Google because it goes against their policy. But, of course, this is possible.